# The Namespace * already contains a definition for *

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've created a separate folder and pages in my ASP.NET web application.  When I build the solution, I receive the error

```
The Namespace MyApp already contains a defintion for VDS
```

Here's the contents of VDS.Master.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MayApp{
public partial class VDS : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Here's the content of VDS.Master.designer.cs:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated. 
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace MyApp.VDS {


public partial class VDS {

    /// <summary>
    /// Head1 control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlHead Head1;

    /// <summary>
    /// head control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.ContentPlaceHolder head;

    /// <summary>
    /// form1 control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm form1;

    /// <summary>
    /// ScriptManager1 control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::System.Web.UI.ScriptManager ScriptManager1;

    /// <summary>
    /// NavMenu control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu NavMenu;

    /// <summary>
    /// smds1 control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.SiteMapDataSource smds1;

    /// <summary>
    /// MainContent control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.ContentPlaceHolder MainContent;

    /// <summary>
    /// lblfoot control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Auto-generated field.
    /// To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
    /// </remarks>
```

Here's the content of VDS.Master:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="True" CodeBehind="VDS.Master.cs" Inherits="MyApp.VDS.VDS" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Dealer Services</title>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<link href="Styles/master.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">


<div class="container"> 
<div class="header">
<h1>Welcome to Dealer Services </h1>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
</div>
<div class=" clear nav">
    <asp:Menu runat="server" ID="NavMenu" BackColor="Silver" DataSourceID="smds1" 
        DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="0.8em" 
        ForeColor="White" Orientation="Horizontal" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px">
        <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#284E98" ForeColor="White" />
        <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
        <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#B5C7DE" />
        <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#507CD1" />
        <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#284E98" ForeColor="White" />
        <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
        <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#507CD1" />
    </asp:Menu>
    <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="smds1" runat="server" ShowStartingNode="False" />
</div>
<div class="login">
</div>
<div class="content">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="MainContent" runat="server">

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
<div class="footer">
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblfoot">&trade; Veehco Inc. 2011</asp:Label>
</div>


</div>  


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried deleting the VDS.Master.designer.cs file, but the error is returned upon each build.  How do I rectify this issue?

Thanks much!

Comment: is the "namespace MayApp" a typo in your question or a typo in your code?

Comment: Any other files in that project declaring this class?

Comment: 1. have you tried a "clean solution" (Build -> Clean Solution in Visual Studio)?  2. have you searched your code for other classes called "VDS"?

Comment: The other VDS class would have to be set as a partial as well. is it?

Comment: @Zach:  Sorry, should be MyApp instead of MayApp

Comment: @Fosco:  the only two files involved are VDS.Master.cs and VDS.Master.designer.cs

Comment: @Paolo:  I did the clean solution and then built again, same error persists :(

Comment: @SidC - Any luck getting this error resolved?

Comment: @Joel:  Unfortunately, the error is not yet resolved.  I've tried deleting the VDS.Master and the build succeeds.  When I re-create it, the error returns :(

Comment: @SidC - Are you putting creating VDS.Master in a folder called VDS or have a VDS folder in your project somewhere? Namespaces automatically get created after the folder names, so that could be causing the clash. If so, try deleting VDS.master, renaming the folder to something else, and then recreating VDS.master. If you have any other files created in that folder or subfolders, you'll want to remove them as well because they'll have clashing namespaces as well.

Comment: @Joel:  Yes, I have a folder named VDS and have two files in that folder.  VDS.Master resides in the document root of the site.  I removed the folder and deleted, then recreated VDS.master and the content pages in the folder.  Unfortunately the build error persists.  How do I locate the entries for the VDS namespace and remove those that are clashing?

Comment: @SidC - Just to clarify, when you recreated the folder, did you name it something other than VDS? A good rule of thumb is to not name any folders the same name as any of your classes (including master pages, usercontrols, etc).

Comment: @SidC - The namespace declaration is added automatically when you create the file, so the good news is you can change it afterwards and it'll stay the way you change it. The namespace declarations I'm referring to are the lines near the top of each file that start with "namespace", such as "namespace MyApp.VDS". Essentially that's declaring a namespace called VDS inside of the MyApp namespace. You'd want to remove all references to VDS in all of your namespace declarations (so "namespace MyApp" for example) otherwise they'll clash with your masterpage.

Comment: @SidC - You can think of namespaces as containers used to keep things organized. In order for classes to see each other, they have to be in the same container or you have to tell it about the other namespace (e.g. that's what all the using statements at the very top do.) When you say "namespace MyApp.VDS", you are creating a VDS container inside of the MyApp container. If you also have a class called VDS, the compiler can't figure out if you're referring to the class or to the namespace.

Comment: @Joel Thanks much!!  I had deleted, re-created, renamed the master and folder names so many times.  I found a unique naming convention I hadn't used, created the new master page and content pages. The build now succeeeds.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any chance you converted it to a Web Application from a Web Site? I've seen this problem caused by the conversion sometimes.

The first line of your VDS.master file probably looks something like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="VDS.master.cs" Inherits="VDS" %>
```

The problem, in my case at least, was that it was using the `CodeFile` attribute instead of `CodeBehind`. If your project is indeed a Web Application and your line above contains `CodeFile`, you'll want to change it to `CodeBehind` so it looks something like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="VDS.master.cs" Inherits="VDS" %>
```

The reason for the error is due to the way these two attributes are handled:

- CodeBehind: Needs to be compiled
  before being deployed and the
  compiled assembly is put in the bin
  folder of your website.
- CodeFile: You deploy the source and it is compiled
  as it is needed. The compiled
  assembly is placed in the Temporary
  ASP.NET folder.

If your project is a web application but it is using the CodeFile attribute, it ends up being compiled by you, then compiled at runtime as well resulting in two different assemblies which containg definitions for the same classes. Then everything explodes.

Comment: The first line does have the CodeBehind attribute and is set to MyApp.VDS.

Comment: Darn... I was hoping that this was the problem. Perhaps it is just a typo, but you said that your CodeBehind attribute points to "MyApp.VDS" -- it should be pointing to "VDS.Master.cs" and not the namespace.

Comment: Sorry, was looking at the Inherits attribute:  Codebehind="VDS.Master.cs" Inherits="MyApp.VDS.VDS"

Comment: I figured that was the case. Just checking though. Not really sure what the problem is then. Could you post the rest of your code (the .cs, .master, and designer files)?

Answer (score 5):

Do you by any chance have a file named the same as the namespace?

For example, the master file is named the same as the namespace and the project!

Comment: OMG! OMG! I did have my project in the same FOLDER as the namespace I was using. Thank you! I've been trying all of these suggestions on here for the last 3 days after work (personal website).

Comment: Mine was a Web Application to begin with, so no conversion had been made as described in the accepted answer. I had added a master page with the namespace WebApp.LoggedIn.Export.ExportPage, and there was another masterpage named LoggedIn in the namespace WebApp.MasterPages

Answer (score 0):

In the designer and .master file, you have a namespace of VDS which conflicts with the VDS class.

Change the inherits in the .master from:

```
Inherits="MyApp.VDS.VDS"
```

to:

```
Inherits="MyApp.VDS"
```

and the designer file from:

```
namespace MyApp.VDS {
```

to:

```
namespace MyApp {
```

Answer (score 0):

Joel is right on the mark, I had the same problem and was inclined to rename and take shortcut. But on taking time to investigate was worth reestablishing confidence with the tool.

I had an Admin class in my project in namespace MyNameSpace.

And I was trying to create MyNamespage.Admin.

I changed Admin class to Administrator and it works.

Answer (score 0):

This mean you already have 1 define VDS some where in your namespace, you must find out.
It's usually occur because you move or edit file in VS Studio

In your case,

```
namespace MyApp{
public partial class VDS : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
```

That mean, you already define MayApp.VDS

after that. in your design

```
namespace MyApp.VDS {

public partial class VDS {
```

MyApp.VDS not a namespace, VDS is a class

so you just delete vds in your design file
now will be

```
namespace MyApp{

public partial class VDS {
```