# ASP.NET Framework 4 client callback demo code complains about ListBox1

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, callback, postback

From this set of ASP.NET demo code:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178209.aspx

in VS2010 in an ASP.NET project, I get error message:

"The name 'ListBox1' does not exist in the current context" from the C# source file where the ListBox1 is referenced (lines 35-37).  If I add a declaration for the ListBox1 within the class, the error goes away but when I press F5 to run it, I get a message that the ListBox1 has already been defined.  What have I missed?

ClientCallback.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class ClientCallback : System.Web.UI.Page,
 System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler
{
// protected ListBox ListBox1;
protected System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary catalog;
protected String returnValue;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String cbReference =
        Page.ClientScript.GetCallbackEventReference(this,
        "arg", "ReceiveServerData", "context");
    String callbackScript;
    callbackScript = "function CallServer(arg, context)" +
        "{ " + cbReference + ";}";
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),
        "CallServer", callbackScript, true);

    catalog = new System.Collections.Specialized.ListDictionary();
    catalog.Add("monitor", 12);
    catalog.Add("laptop", 10);
    catalog.Add("keyboard", 23);
    catalog.Add("mouse", 17);

    ListBox1.DataSource = catalog;
    ListBox1.DataTextField = "key";
    ListBox1.DataBind();

}

public void RaiseCallbackEvent(String eventArgument)
{
    if (catalog[eventArgument] == null)
    {
        returnValue = "-1";
    }
    else
    {
        returnValue = catalog[eventArgument].ToString();
    }
}
public String GetCallbackResult()
{
    return returnValue;
}
}
```

and ClientCallback.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeFile="ClientCallback.aspx.cs" Inherits="ClientCallback" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 
1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html  >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Client Callback Example</title>
<script type="text/ecmascript">
  function LookUpStock() {
      var lb = document.getElementById("<%=ListBox1.ClientID%>");
      try {
          var product = lb.options[lb.selectedIndex].text;
          CallServer(product, "");
      }
      catch (err) {
          alert("Please select a product.");
      }
  }

  function ReceiveServerData(rValue) {
      document.getElementById("<%=ResultsSpan.ClientID%>").innerHTML = rValue;

  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
  <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" Runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
  <br />
  <br />
  <input type="button" value="Look Up Stock" onclick="LookUpStock()" />
  <br />
  <br />
  Items in stock: <span id="ResultsSpan" runat="server"></span>
  <br />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your ClientCallBack.aspx.designer.vb class is not declaring the listbox. Copy the code exactly like you did before from the website and then put this line of code in the code behind

```
  Protected WithEvents ListBox As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListBox
```

Implements System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler
         
   Protected catalog As ListDictionary

Now edit these two lines in the markup:

Line 11 change ListBox1 to ListBox
Line 26 change Listbox1 to ListBox

You should be golden.

Hope that helps

Comment: I must be reading your suggestions incorrectly.  Will that work with the C# code in the demo?  I tried them and still no luck.  Do I need to add in some code to the ClientCallback.aspx.designer.cs source file or the ClientCallback.aspx.cs source file?

Comment: Got it working.  I needed to specify "CodeBehind" not "CodeFile" in the .aspx file.

Comment: Steve because of the way partial classes work you can put it in the designer or the codebehind its cleaner to put it in the designer but both works. If this worked can you please up vote ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this other article, I think it addresses your issue:
[The Namespace * already contains a definition for *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061972/the-namespace-already-contains-a-defintion-for)

I think the deal is that these example files are set up for an ASP.Net "Web Site", where you are using an ASP.Net "Web Project" (which most people also use).

If you look at the ASPX file, change the **CodeFile** to **CodeBehind**, it should work with your declaration in the codebehind.

Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
**CodeFile**="ClientCallback.aspx.cs" Inherits="ClientCallback"

A "Web Site" type of project doesn't use declarations in the code behind, but hardly anybody uses that project type anymore, so not sure why they set up the example that way.