# Error in Masterpage, namespace already exists

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I want to add some code into my masterpage. So I removed the namespace but when I want to test it it gives this error. No idea how to fix this.

> Error  2   The namespace 'Project' in 'c:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\project\fe95a550\6aff5a12\assembly\dl3\9f54421a\e011b011_23bccd01\Project.DLL' conflicts with the type 'Project' in 'c:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\project\fe95a550\6aff5a12\App_Web_exfemb4u.dll'  c:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\project\fe95a550\6aff5a12\App_Web_hrdlxq5l.4.cs    154

Masterpage.cs

```
public partial class Project: System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

Masterpage

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Project.master.cs" Inherits="Project" %>
```

Comment: Change your master page's name to something other than `Project` . as your project's name as well as you master page are name `Project`. It is creating conflict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you add a namespace before public partial ....

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class MovieMeter : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
         }
    }
}
```

Why did you remove the namespace ? please add one.

Comment: I get this error
Error 3 The namespace '<global namespace>' already contains a definition for 'Project' C:\ProjectAsp\Project\Project.Master.cs 15 11 C:\ProjectAsp\Project\

Comment: Did you try to change the namespace name just to see if the error change ?

Comment: Look at that thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061972/the-namespace-already-contains-a-defintion-for

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Project.master.cs" Inherits="Project" %>
```

With:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Project.master.cs" Inherits="Project" %>
```

It might solve...

Then the reason for the error is due to the way these two attributes are handled:

*CodeBehind*: Needs to be compiled before being deployed and the compiled assembly is put in the bin folder of your website.

*CodeFile*: You deploy the source and it is compiled as it is needed. The compiled assembly is placed in the Temporary ASP.NET folder.

Comment: Still an error
Error 3 Could not load type 'Project'. C:\ProjectAsp\Project\Project.Master 3

Answer (score 0):

Change your master page's name to something other than **Project** . as your project's name as well as you master page are name **Project**. It is creating conflict.